# Trouble with timers and threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm a learn-by-example C# coder who isn't very advanced, which is why this problem is completely stumping me regardless of the amount of information on the internet.

I'm essentially creating a program that is, on a timer, repeatedly polling a website to get some information.  During this process, a WebBrowser control is created to navigate to the information (needed for authentication).  The program runs this series of events at startup, then using a System.Timers.Timer set to every 10 minutes (less for debugging of course) to do that same series of events yet when my Timer.Elapsed event triggers that process, I get a:

**ThreadStateException** with the description as *ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.*

Here is a slimmed down version of my program.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetDataFromWebBrowser();
            Set_Auto_Refresh_Timer();
        }

private void Set_Auto_Refresh_Timer()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer TimerRefresh = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
            TimerRefresh.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerRefresh_Elapsed);
            TimerRefresh.AutoReset = true;
            TimerRefresh.Start();
        }    

private void TimerRefresh_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetDataFromWebBrowser();
        }

private void GetDataFromWebBrowser()
        {
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();  <--This is where the error is thrown.

            ...get web data...

        }
```

I think I got enough code in there to paint the picture.  As you can see, when it gets to creating another WebBrowser, it throws the error.

I'm really stumped and I'm just starting to scrape the surface on Threading which is probably why I'm so stumped.

//Solution for me/
I ended up moving the WebBrowser creation out of the method as well as making it static to just reuse the WebBrowser control.  I also swapped my System.Timers.Timer to System.Threading.Timer.  Seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: It is because the WebBrowser control isn't allowed in its own thread. Can you use a WebClient instead ? Else there's a [STAThread] attribute for methods.. not sure if that works..

Comment: I don't know the WebBrowser control, but usually Controls can only be used in the thread the Form runs in. You could switch to a System.Windows.Forms.Timer (you won't be multithreading in that case) or go the harder way and use WebRequest (requires some work to get authorisation working)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation for WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) states that:

> The WebBrowser class can only be used in threads set to single thread apartment (STA) mode. To use this class, ensure that your Main method is **marked with the [STAThread] attribute**.

Also, change your `System.Timers.Timer` to a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` if you want to interact with UI controls in regular intervals. Alternatively, set the [SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property of your `System.Timers.Timer` to a parent control to force your timer to invoke calls on the right thread. All WinForms controls can only be accessed from the same, one and only UI thread.

There are three types of timers in .NET's BCL, each of them acting very differently. Check this MSDN article for a comparison: [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library (web archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) or this [brief comparison table](https://mitch-wheat.blogspot.hr/2010/12/comparing-net-timer-classes.html).

Comment: I've attempted to swap over the auto_refresh timer to a Windows.Form.Timer but it won't fire the .Tick event and I'm not sure why.  The documentation doesn't give me any hints as to why either.

Comment: @Josh: that's strange. Are you sure you started it? And the `Interval` value is reasonable? Can you post your code?

Comment: The [STAThread] attribute didn't actually work but as you suggested that I swap to a different timer, which did help - along with some other code modifications.  Interval value was 30seconds or so for testing.  I ended up going with Threading.Timer, which worked fine for my spaghetti code.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class instead of WebBrowser. Also it seems to be better to store already created instance as a private property instead of creating new instance each time you need to poll a web site.

As following:

```
private WebClient webClient;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetDataFromWebBrowser();
            Set_Auto_Refresh_Timer();
            this.webClient = new WebClient();
        }

private void Set_Auto_Refresh_Timer()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer.TimerRefresh = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
            TimerRefresh.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerRefresh_Elapsed);
            TimerRefresh.AutoReset = true;
            TimerRefresh.Start();
        }    

private void Set_Auto_Refresh_Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetDataFromWebBrowser();
        }

private void GetDataFromWebBrowser()
        {
            ...perform required work with webClient...
            ...get web data...

        }
```

Comment: +1 Yes, that's the proper way, actually. Creating a control which won't interact with the user is wrong.

Comment: The choice was made to use WebBrowser because I spent an inordinate amount of time trying to get a WebClient to work but couldn't get the authentication process to succeed.  WebClient was my first choice.

Comment: For authentication you can pass an instance of [NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) class. It was enough for me to specify login, password and domain name as in following `new NetworkCredential("userId", "password", "domainName");`.

Comment: Yeah, tried that with a couple of different other ways.  I really wish it would have worked but I just couldn't get it to go.

Answer (score 0):

As Groo said, you should use **System.Windows.Forms.Timer**, or if you really want to do you operation in another thread, you should use the Invoke method to do any UI related stuff:

```
private void GetWebData()
{
     ...get web data...
}

private void ShowWebData()
{
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    // other UI stuff
}

private void TimerRefresh_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    GetDataFromWebBrowser();
}

private void GetDataFromWebBrowser()
{
    GetWebData();

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(new Action(ShowWebData));
    else
        ShowWebData();
}
```