# Multiple WebBrowsers in one program

Tags: c#, multithreading, browser

My problem is that I cannot run multiple Webbrowsers the same time.

When I want to scrap data using `webbrowser1` from site1 and scrap another data using `webbrowser2` from site2, only the first `webbrowser` is doing the job.

I tried to run them in separate threads, but it didn't work, too. I heard something about STA ApartmentState before `main`, but it is present there and still nothing.

How I can make both webbrowsers work in the same time ?

Comment: Why don't you use a WebClient or a raw Proxy. They are not that hard to use.

Answer (score 2):

If the website you are trying to scrap data from does not dynamically change HTML through JavaScript you can simply use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this. It is best in my view and easy to work with. This will solve your problem of multiple browsers as you can asynchronously scrap data from multiple websites using different instance of `HtmlDocument` in different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the `WebBrowser` is an ActiveX component that can only run in a single-threaded environment. A similar question was asked recently: [Trouble with timers and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076041/trouble-with-timers-and-threads)

My suggestion is to use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class instead to fetch data from multiple locations at the same time.